# Navigation package without pcl

Tags: pcl, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I am looking for a navigation package which I can use to plan and follow a path in a 2D-plane. Because I am using a Raspberry PI in combination with the Navio2 (emlid Raspian OS) and a RPLidar I am not able to use the PCL library(and is also not necessary because I only use a 2D-scan I think). The OS has also no GUI. Is there some way to change the navigation package in ros so that PCL is not required? Or are there also other packages available?

Kind regards,
Stef

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286938/navigation-package-without-pcl/) by [Stef_Boat](https://answers.ros.org/users/34241/stef_boat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-03-28

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit: ROS Melodic includes a PCL-free version of the ROS navigation stack!

*Original Answer: Unfortunately, we haven't migrated away from PCL yet in the ROS navigation stack (there are open issues/pull requests around it, such as https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues/264).*

*If you're feeling ambitious, there is a massive PR here: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/pull/458 that migrates kinetic-devel branch away from PCL, using the iterators. We've never gotten around to fully testing it. I am targeting to actually test/merge that for Melodic over the next several weeks, because it's way overdue.*

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2018-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3